# Broadcast receiver goAsync

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

An android receiver has a short lifetime, no more than 10 seconds. Is the `goAsync()` method a way to "bypass" this limit? If no, what is the real goal of `goAsync()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It changes the thread so you can do computationally heavy work without freezing the UI thread.  Read the docs:

" This does not change the expectation of being relatively responsive to the broadcast (finishing it within 10s), but does allow the implementation to move work related to it over to another thread to avoid glitching the main UI thread due to disk IO."

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand if the thread can be executed for more than 10 seconds or not. I don't understand if the first sentence is related to the background thread or not. If the 10 seconds limit is always true, then the goAsync() has got really a limited worth.

Comment: The 10 second rule still is enforced, on both threads.  If you need more than 10 seconds, you need to create a Service.  goAsync is a very limited usecase.

Comment: Using Aysnc i got following error "
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
Broadcast already finished
"  How to solve this?